# Comparing observed gradient

Tags: experimental-physics

Just working through an experiment to find G, and I have been asked to compare my observed gradient and constant with the expected values.
I was wondering what is generally considered acceptable to use as a comparison? Is the p value the best measure?

Comment: It will depend on what you were taught, this is a better question for the instructor of the class. The below answer is good yes, but we dont know how you've been taught to compare experimental values to theoretical ones. For instance in the simple undergrad labs I teach, it's enough to say whether or not the theoretical value lies within the interval $\bar{G}_{exp}\pm \sigma_{G_{exp}}$ where one calculates some average G and it's uncertainty $\sigma_G$ using some form of statistical analysis.

Comment: Thank you, my lecturer hasn't specified any specific way to evaluate it as we haven't really covered that in the course, so I will use the standard deviation method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good practice to present the steps which you used to calculate the $p$-value. Hence, if you show that

1. the average value of your experiment is $\bar g = 10.1m/s^2$,
2. the standard deviation associated with the average value is $s=Sd[\bar g] = 0.2m/s^2$,

most people are able to eyeball the $p$-value of the hypothesis test. Thus, your result can be understood instead of merely accepted. In my opinion this is the proper way of presenting your findings.

It is also good practice to present plots of the result. E.g. if I expect a straight line, but most data-points are scattered considerably around this line, I get a feeling of the uncertainty associated with each datapoint. Just stating the $R^2$ of the fit does not provide this intuitive understanding.  So don't try to be brief in discussing your result. Instead, try to take different perspectives, and present your data in different forms.